# My android app does not work when I rebuild and deploy

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I have a code showing the Google map and the user can view the address of the location by tapping on the map. When I run the software for the first time on my phone, it works. But when I make changes to the appearance of the software, such as changing the image of the software application icon, It's not like the first one. Shows the map But by tapping on the map does not show the address. Also, if I create the new project with the same code, It works fine for the first time. But from the next few times, it only shows the map.

```
package com.example.ghappmgis4;

import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class GoogleSatelliteMapShow extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.google_satellite_map);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.googlesatellitemap);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng Tehran = new LatLng(35, 51);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Tehran).title("ایران"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Tehran));
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
        mMap.setOnMapClickListener((new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), " click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("DEBUG","Map clicked[" + point.latitude + "/" + point.longitude + "]");
                Geocoder geoCoder= new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                try {
                    List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(point.latitude, point.longitude, 1);
                    String add = "";
                    if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                        /**for (int i = 0; i < addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
                         add += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i)+" ";**/
                        add += addresses.get(0).getCountryName()+" ";
                        add += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)+" ";

                    }
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), add, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }));

    }
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_3:
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1:
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomOut());
                break;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode,event);
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/googlesatellitemap"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    map:uiZoomControls="true"
    tools:context=".GoogleSatelliteMapShow"
```

### />

```
06-16 00:13:27.573 30458-30458/com.example.ghappmgis4 D/DEBUG: Map clicked[2.8225890364293718/51.04967750608921]
06-16 00:13:27.943 30458-30458/com.example.ghappmgis4 W/System.err: java.io.IOException: grpc failed
06-16 00:13:27.943 30458-30458/com.example.ghappmgis4 W/System.err:     at android.location.Geocoder.getFromLocation(Geocoder.java:136)
06-16 00:13:27.943 30458-30458/com.example.ghappmgis4 W/System.err:     at com.example.ghappmgis4.GoogleSatelliteMapShow$1.onMapClick(GoogleSatelliteMapShow.java:63)
06-16 00:13:27.943 30458-30458/com.example.ghappmgis4 W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzy.onMapClick(Unknown Source)
06-16 00:13:27.943 30458-30458/com.example.ghappmgis4 W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzak.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source)
06-16 00:13:27.943 30458-30458/com.example.ghappmgis4 W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zzb.onTransact(Unknown Source)
06-16 00:13:27.943 30458-30458/com.example.ghappmgis4 W/System.err:     at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
06-16 00:13:27.943 30458-30458/com.example.ghappmgis4 W/System.err:     at hn.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17528027@17.5.28 (020300-252519129):14)
06-16 00:13:27.943 30458-30458/com.example.ghappmgis4 W/System.err:     at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.av.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17528027@17.5.28 (020300-252519129):4)
06-16 00:13:27.943 30458-30458/com.example.ghappmgis4 W/System.err:     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.api.aa.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17528027@17.5.28 (020300-252519129):8)
06-16 00:13:27.943 30458-30458/com.example.ghappmgis4 W/System.err:     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.ah.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17528027@17.5.28 (020300-252519129):132)
06-16 00:13:27.943 30458-30458/com.example.ghappmgis4 W/System.err:     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.da.onSingleTapConfirmed(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17528027@17.5.28 (020300-252519129):22)
06-16 00:13:27.943 30458-30458/com.example.ghappmgis4 W/System.err:     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.gesture.a.onSingleTapConfirmed(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17528027@17.5.28 (020300-252519129):240)
06-16 00:13:27.943 30458-30458/com.example.ghappmgis4 W/System.err:     at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.gesture.c.handleMessage(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@17528027@17.5.28 (020300-252519129):9)
06-16 00:13:27.943 30458-30458/com.example.ghappmgis4 W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-16 00:13:27.943 30458-30458/com.example.ghappmgis4 W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
06-16 00:13:27.943 30458-30458/com.example.ghappmgis4 W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
06-16 00:13:27.943 30458-30458/com.example.ghappmgis4 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-16 00:13:27.943 30458-30458/com.example.ghappmgis4 W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
06-16 00:13:27.943 30458-30458/com.example.ghappmgis4 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
06-16 00:13:27.953 30458-30458/com.example.ghappmgis4 W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
06-16 00:13:33.863 30458-30475/com.example.ghappmgis4 I/art: Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3664(144KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 56% free, 9MB/21MB, paused 1.489ms total 58.644ms
```

Comment: Can you attach the error log?

Comment: Yes. I attach the error log.